# How to Plot Several 3D Trajectories in Julia (using a for-loop, presumably?) -- also, how to animate over time?

Tags: animation, plot, julia

I am trying to plot a set of 3D trajectories in a single plot in Julia. By 3-D trajectories I mean: different sets of 3-D coordinates over time. These trajectories are stored in a multidimensional array called `positions`, where the dimensions respectively correspond to the `Trajectory ID`, `X-Y-Z coordinate` and `Time`. For example, `positions[75,2,1:100]` refers to the Y (2nd) coordinate of the 75th Trajectory, across the first 100 timesteps of the trajectory.

I am trying to figure out why the following code doesn't work:

```
using Plots

plotlyjs()

time_indices = 1:100

ax= scatter3d(positions[1,1,time_indices],positions[1,2,time_indices],positions[1,3,time_indices],label="Trajectory 1 for times 1 to 100")

for n in 2:size(positions,1)
    scatter3d!(ax, positions[n,1,time_indices], positions[n,2,time_indices],positions[n,3,time_indices],label="Trajectory $n for times 1 to 100")
end
```

When I run that code, I don't see anything in the Plots window (I'm using Atom), although I don't get any errors / it appears to run successfully. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Should I use a different backend? It doesn't work on either `gr()` or `plotlyjs()` (those are the only ones I know of, based on tutorials I've completed).

Follow up question: once I can successfully plot such 3-D trajectories in a single static plot, I am wondering how you would go about animating them over time (using `@gif` or `@animate` macros, presumably)? I am asking this here, because I wasn't able to understand the documentation / tutorial on 3D animations, unfortunately. Googling / other sources have also not helped :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're just missing a `display(ax)` at the end, after the loop.

Edit: to animate, try

```
anim = @animate for n in 1:size(positions,1)
    scatter3d(positions[n,1,time_indices], positions[n,2,time_indices],positions[n,3,time_indices],label="Trajectory $n for times 1 to 100")
end
gif(anim, "some_file_name.gif", fps=15)
```

(or if you want the prior trajectories to show up as well in later frames of the gif, then replace the `scatter3d` with `scatter3d!`)

I can't test the above without having your `positions`, but here is another example that I have just tested on Julia 1.5.0beta with Plots and the GR backend:

```
using Plots; gr();
anim = @animate for i=1:100
    plot(sin.(range(0,i/10*pi,length=1000)), label="", ylims=(-1,1))
end
gif(anim, "anim_fps15.gif", fps=15)
```

Comment: You're right! Thanks for that, I'm clearly very new to Julia haha. If you have any idea about how to animate, additionally - that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it worked! Edited to add suggestion on animation

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment. The problem I'm facing with the suggested^ code is that it visibly draws each full trajectory (of trajectory `n`) before drawing the next one. Namely, for each 'frame' there's a small, detectable lag between plotting trajectory `n` and trajectory `n+1`. And when it draws them, it redraws the full time course of trajectory `n` from the beginning (when using `!scatter3d`). What I'm imagining (and apologies for not clarifying this in the original comment) is to see the instantaneous position of each 'particle' _at each timepoint_ ...

Comment: ...without any lag between the drawing of individual particles _at a given timepoint_. Imagine a visualization of a swarm of particles (e.g. a school of fish), for instance, where each trajectory corresponds to the X,Y,Z coordinates over time of a single fish in the school. I want to plot the whole ensemble of fish at a given time point, and then the 'step' in the frame or gif comes between successive time points, not between successive fish. I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: I think I figured it out -- see the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

How to do the second bit (the animation - see details in comments on the accepted answer):

```
gr()
anim = @animate for t in time_indices
    all_positions_t = positions[:,:,t] # positions of all trajectories at time t
    scatter3d(all_positions_t[:,1], all_positions_t[:,2],all_positions_t[:,3],label="")
end
gif(anim, "some_file_name.gif", fps=15)
```